# A weak form diagonal dominance and positive semidefiniteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the following nonstandard form of diagonal dominance: Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be symmetric and assume that for all $i$, 
$$
   |a_{ii}| > |a_{ij}|, \quad j \neq i
$$
Is there a matrix with such property that is not positive semidefinite? I am mainly interested in the case where $a_{ij} \in [0,1]$ for all $i,j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Running `A=rand(3);A=(A+A')/2;A=A-diag(diag(A))+eye(3);` gave me after few tries a matrix

```
A =

1.0000    0.1394    0.7938
0.1394    1.0000    0.7389
0.7938    0.7389    1.0000
```

which is indefinite.

Comment: It would have been nice to have some understanding of when this happens.

Comment: @passerby51 Even a simpler example $\pmatrix{1&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&1&1}$ reveals that this simple criterion is not enough. A certain diagonal dominance is satisfied by all SPD matrices: $|a_{ij}|^2\leq a_{ii}a_{jj}$ for all $i$ and $j$ which is simply due to the fact that any $2\times 2$ principal submatrix of an SPD matrix is SPD as well. Having all $2\times 2$ principal submatrices of a symmetric matrix SPD, however, does not imply that the matrix itself is SPD (it is only necessary, not sufficient).